# How do I plot counts of values in each column on a single chart using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
values = [[True, True, True, False, False],
          [False, True, True, True, False], 
          [True, True, False, False, False], 
          [False, False, False, False, True]]

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
dummy_df
```

[image: and]

How will I plot this as a grouped bar chart using matplotlib?
I want the result to look something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can coun each column in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), transpose and call [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
cols = list('ABCDE')
values = [[True, True, True, False, False],
          [False, True, True, True, False], 
          [True, True, False, False, False], 
          [False, False, False, False, True]]

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
```

```
dummy_df.apply(pd.value_counts).T.plot.bar()
```

---

[image: g]